# What does Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget do?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

I've been reading about `Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget`, which is a [XAML attached property on Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control?view=winrt-19041#xaml-attached-properties).

The documentation is sparse:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether this element is the part of a control template that has the focus visual.
>
> [...]
>
> This property is for use in a ControlTemplate only. If it's set outside of a ControlTemplate, it's ignored. If this attached property is set more than once in a ControlTemplate, an exception is thrown.

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can determine, `Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget` is pretty much as described in [that short documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control?view=winrt-19041#xaml-attached-properties):

If you set `Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="true"` on an element in a ControlTemplate (for example, if you are re-templating a CheckBox), the visual focus rectangle will appear on that item rather than around the whole template.

---

Interestingly, I believe `Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget` also works on DataTemplates in some cases, like for a ListView.

This simple ListView uses `Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget` in its `ItemTemplate` to show the focus rect around just the TextBlock:

[image: screenshot of items in a ListView with the middle item focused, but the focus rectangle is around the text in the item, not the whole item.]

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
                  CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
                  SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
                        <Button Content="Foo" IsTabStop="False" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Interestingly, this behavior does not seem to nest: if your `DataTemplate` loads a UserControl (`<MyGreatListViewItemTemplate Item="{x:Bind}" />`), `Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget` will not have any affect within that code.